# How solve error in this python program?

Tags: python, function, output, indentation

i m a beginner in python and i have lots and lots of questions about it.I tried to create a program and i m not getting the result exactly.Only little calculation is there,rest is printed matter.

it goes like this:

```
 def travelmanagement():
  trate=[]
  totrate=[]
  finrate=[]
  frate=[]
  print"WELCOME TO..........MESSAGE"
  print"ARE YOU A VISITOR OR MEMBER"
  ch1=raw_input("Enter your choice")
  V="VISITOR"
  v="visitor"
  if(ch1==V)|(ch1==v):
           print"To proceed further,you need to a create account/use guest session"
           print"A.Create Account"
           print"B.Guest Session"
           ch2=raw_input("Enter your choice")
           if(ch2=="A")|(ch2=="a"):
                     Name=raw_input("Enter your name:")
                     Username=raw_input("ENter your username")
                     Password=raw_input("ENter your password")
                     Confirm=raw_input("Confirm your password")
                     DOB=raw_input("DD: MM: YY: ")
                     Gender=raw_input("I am....")
                     Mobile=input("Enter your mobile number")
                     Location=raw_input("Enter your current location")
                     print"Prove you are not a robot,Type the text shown below"
                     print"trufle"
                     text="trufle"
                     type=raw_input("Type your text")
                     if(Password==Confirm)&(type==text):#proceed works only after if  is satisfied
                                       def proceed():
                                             print"You have created account"
                                             print"You can now proceed!!"
                                             print"Welcome",Username
                                             print"TMS specializes in touristplaces"
                                             print"P1.DELHI"
                                             print"P2.GOA"
                                             ch3=raw_input("What's your destination?")
                                             pl=['delhi','goa']
                                             t=['t','c','b','p']
                                             gp=[200,400]#general #rate for choosing place
                                             gt=[200,300,400,500]#general rate for choosing transportation
                                             print"""TMS specializez
                                             t.Railways
                                             c.Car
                                             b.Bus
                                             p.Plane"""
                                             ch4=raw_input("ENter your choice")
                                             if(ch4=="t"):#displays timmings of transportation
                                                     print"HYPERSONIC HAIRTRIGGER"
                                                     print "Timmings:"
                                                     print "DELHI"
                                                     print ".............."
                                                     print "GOA"
                                                     print ".............."
                                                     print "VELOCIOUS PALACE"
                                                     print "Timming"
                                             if(ch4=="c"):
                                                      print"CArs available:"
                                                      print"BMW"
                                                      print"SWIFT"
                                                      print"......."
                                                      print"........"
                                             if(ch4=="b"):
                                                      print"Buses available"
                                                      print"................"
                                                      print"""delhi
                                                      timiings
                                                      .........
                                                      goa

                                                      .................."""

                                             if(ch4=="p"):
                                                      print"""Planes available
                                                      ........just like abv"""
                                             for i in range(0,2,1):
                                                        for j in range(0,4,1):
                                                            if(pl[i]==ch3)&(t[j]==ch4):
                                                                     trate=gp[i]*gt[j]

                                             return ch3,ch4      

                                       def accomodation():

                                                    print"""specialises
                                                    1.place 1
                                                    a.hotel 1
                                                    b.hotel 2
                                                    Hotel1:ac/non ac rooms
                                                    Ac.for ac...
                                                    Noac.for non ac....
                                                    b.Hotel2
                                                    Ac.ac..
                                                    Noac.non ac...
                                                    2.place 2
                                                    a.Hotel1:ac/non ac rooms
                                                    A.for ac...
                                                    N.for non ac...
                                                    b.Hotel2
                                                    A.ac..
                                                    N.non ac..."""
                                                    genh1=[5000]#general rate for choosing hotel1
                                                    genh2=[4000]#general rate for choosing hotel2
                                                    ch5=input("Enter ypur choice")
                                                    fav=raw_input("ENter hotel choice")
                                                    mode=raw_input("Enter ac/no ac")
                                                    TAc=[1000]#rate for ac room
                                                    Nac=[400]#rate for non ac room
                                                    if(ch5==1):
                                                         if(fav=="a"):
                                                             if(mode=="Ac"):
                                                                 frate=genh1+TAc
                                                             else:
                                                                  frate=genh1+Nac
                                                         elif(fav=="b"):
                                                               if(mode=="Ac"):
                                                                   frate=genh2+TAc
                                                               else:
                                                                    frate=genh2+Nac
                                                    elif(ch5==2):
                                                           if(fav=="a"):
                                                               if(mode=="Ac"):
                                                                    frate=genh1+TAc
                                                               else:
                                                                   frate=genh1+Nac
                                                           if(fav=="b"):
                                                                if(mode=="Ac"):
                                                                    frate=genh2+TAc
                                                                else:
                                                                    frate=genh2+Nac
                                                    else:
                                                           totrate=totrate+frate+trate
                                                    print"Due to prefer a guide??"
                                                    print"a guide inperson...rate=1000"
                                                    print"maps,3g....rate=2000"
                                                    ch6=raw_input("ENter your choice")
                                                    if(ch6=="person")|(ch6=="PERSON"):
                                                        totrate=totrate+[1000]
                                                    elif(ch6=="gadget"|ch6=="GADGET"):
                                                        totrate=totrate+[2000]
                                                    else:
                                                        return totrate


                                       x=proceed()
                                       y=accomodation()
                                       print x
                                       print y
                      else:
                             print"invalid"


                #if(ch1==b) is present after this.Same lines as above is repeated 
 travelmanagement()
```

indentation is proper.The error is"totrate is referenced before assignment"I gave it in all places where global variables are allowed but still it doesnt come.And when i get the result the amount finrate is not getting printed.instead None or 0 comes.please let me know of the mistakes.Is there something i should import??Sorry for the trouble.Its for a class presentation.
Thanks for your effort.

Comment: That indentation.

Comment: Please correct your indentation, surely your code does not run if it looks like this.

Comment: Your indentation is **not** "proper". Maybe the space in front of the first and last lines is a simple mistake while pasting the code into your question, but the last `else:` (before `print"invalid"`) doesn't match any `if` in your code. Indentation should **always** be four spaces per level; otherwise, you will miss errors like this, and your code will be painful for others to read (which means they won't want to help you debug it).

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl I've rolled back your edit because there's at least one indentation error which suggests OP's code can't run as they claim it does - which is relevant to the answerability of the question.

Comment: `if(ch1==V)|(ch1==v):` ...Despite the fact that this works as you presumably intended in this exact circumstance, you *really* should be using [`or`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) instead of [`|`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations). *Really really really.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

totrate=totrate+frate+trate

you have initialized totrate to be a list. You cannot interact with the list object in this way. I believe you want to be using int types instead of lists. e.g totrate = 1000

Also note, these are not globals but local variables as they are in the scope of the function.

Comment: _"You cannot interact with the list object in this way."_ Well, you _can_ use "+" on lists, as long as the other element is a list too. But I agree that the OP should probably be using ordinary ints.